# Laravel authorization 404

Tags: php, apache, debugging, http-status-code-404, laravel

Been using laravel (current stable version) for 2 days now, and after reading the documentation... played a bit with the templating systems and some other stuff.

Now after installing [Authority](http://vespakoen.github.com/authority-laravel/) bundle along with [Laravel-Administrator](https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator) the problem I have is that when I try opening `http://local.laravel/admin` which redirects me to `http://local.laravel/user/login` and it's when the 404 magic happens.

My logs point good and I really don't know where else or what else to do, to try and debug this... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone beginning with Laravel and stept into this problem, I had to set up the login form in order form, which it's not mentioned in the mentioned Bundle's install tutorials.

1. I changed `user/login` to `login` in `config/administrator.php -> login_path`
2. Added the router to handle the login and logout

More detail in this article http://codehappy.daylerees.com/authentication

Answer (score 0):

I am the creator of the Authority bundle,
All I can tell you is that it doesn't do any redirects, so you will have to look at the administrative bundle.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Hey I wrote the Administrator bundle. Check out this section of the docs:

https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator#installation--documentation

Notice in the config there are several options: auth_check, login_path, and login_redirect_key. What appears to be happening here is that your auth_check is being run, it fails, and then redirects you to the default login_path, which you probably don't have on your system. I'm guessing you haven't set these configuration options up, but they are pretty much required! I set it up this way because I wanted to let devs use their own auth system for the admin panel.

Update: Check out [the configuration docs section](http://administrator.frozennode.com/docs/configuration#permission) on the permission, login_path, and login_redirect_key.

Comment: you forgot to mention that you need to set the login form, for newbies like me :)

Comment: @w0rldart I'll make a video to describe how it works and maybe add something to the readme :)