# laravel Administrator package (frozennode) ,login_path

Tags: php, laravel, package, administrator

I install frozennode Administrator package .it's awesome but I have a problem with it.
when I write 'admin' in the url ,without any login it redirects me to admin page  directly,I need to set permissions so certainly I need the user login. where should I put my login page and connect(redirect) it to admin page after checking? I changed , the administrator.php file for login_path field , many times but it always gives me a not found exeption. I use laravel 4.1 .

thanks for your time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used FrozenNode's Administrator package for some time now, but have you ensured that your config/packages/frozennode/administrator/administrator.php config file has the following in the `permission` key:

```
'permission'=> function () {
    return Auth::check();
},
```

I vaguely recall that it defaults to blank (which means there's no user checking) so you just need to add this in.

It's also worth looking at the `login_path` key in the same config file as it sets the path to which Administrator will redirect an unauthenticated user.

[See here](http://administrator.frozennode.com/docs/configuration) for a description of what the settings in this file do.

It's worth noting that Administrator does not handle your authentication (or authorisation) for you. It does, however, allow you to plug your authentication system in to it, which is why these settings exist. As such the various things you will need to do in order to get Administrator working with authentication is:

- an existing, working, authentication system:

  - login route with form
  - login post form for authentication
  - a way to log out
- edit Administrator's settings to support your auth system and your auth system to work with Administrator:

  - `permission` key should point to a closure that returns true if the user is logged in (and able to access the administration, if you have a more complex auth system) and false if not - in plain Laravel it's a simple `return Auth::check();`
  - `login_path` key should point at the URI to your login form route (if you wish to use named routes, you can use `URL::route('named.route')` for this setting's value)
  - `logout_path` should point at your logout route (ditto above re URIs/named routes)
  - `login_redirect_key` key should be set to whatever value you want to be able to work out the 'intended' URL from after login - when the login form is posted and you successfully authenticate, you redirect to this URL using `return Redirect::to(Session::get('whatever_login_redirect_key_is_set_to'));` - the default is fine here

Comment: thanks for answering . yes I did it but gave me a not found exception . it doesnt find the user/login or any other file and path that I replace in the login_path field.where is the login file exactly?

Comment: ok man :) I think I found it and totally there is no user/login file at all. look at the second answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917665/laravel-authorization-404 .I wish he said that at his tutorial or documentation.it was better for some people with low iq like me. it gave me 2 days.

Comment: Yeah you have to create your own login stuff - he does say in the documentation that Administrator comes with **no** authentication stuff and that the package leave it up to you - so you have to make sure you have a way of checking if someone's logged in (which is what the `permission` anon function is for) and, along with that, you need to create your login routes and views and controller stuff. That's for *you* to do, Administrator handles the actual administration part.

Comment: (See 'Authentication' section at http://administrator.frozennode.com/docs/introduction#installation-guidance for the bit about Administrator not provigin you with an auth system but using your own. I agree it could be clearer though.)

Comment: yes you're right:). and I have just one more question I did something according http://gastonheim.blogspot.com/2013/09/laravel-integrar-sentry-y-administrator.html . but after login I cant connect to admin panel. how can i manage my route that after an admin login so redirect to administrator admin page.(it's my code http://laravel.io/bin/zGe1n). thanks again

Comment: Okay so I think you have a couple of things to do here - first off now you're using Sentry you'll need to update the `permission` anon function (referred to in my answer above) to now use Sentry to check that a perosn is logged in: `'permission' => function () { return Sentry::check(); }` (unless you have more complicated admin rules, in which case I guess they go in there).

Comment: You'll also need to make sure that your login route action correctly uses the `redirect_key` Session variable to redirect the person to the right place after login. See [here](http://administrator.frozennode.com/docs/configuration#redirect-key) for the docs on that, including how to use it. See my fork of your paste [here](http://laravel.io/bin/rYBEL#17) for how I feel this would be achieved.

Comment: @saha thanks for the accept - I have now updated the answer with my advice from these comments to help future searchers

Comment: do you have time to see it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261095/saving-permissions-as-json-in-administrator-for-this-error-cannot-json-decode ... thanks